# Changing XML tag names with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a scenario where I have to remove the numbers from the name of the xml tag. For example, if there is a tag `<xxx1>1234</xxx1>`, I need an output as `<xxx>1234</xxx>`. I surfed through the net and was not able to find a solution. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dom elements children and append to a new dom element in its place rather than changing the element details itself.

Pseudo code:

```
curElementContent = get element from dom and get its contents
newElement = create new dom element

append curElementContent to newElement

remove curElement from dom and insert newElement.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try:

```
tags.replace(/<xxxx\d>/gi, '<xxxx>').replace(/<\/xxxx\d>/gi,'</xxxx>');
```

Where tags contains the string you need to update.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the response. Could you please explain if tags in tags.replace is predefined. Also, can this be used for a complete xml. I will have to loop through the tag name (the xxx value).

Comment: Got it working by converting the xml into an xml string and using the below regex.

    xmlString = xmlString.replace(/\d+>/g, '>');

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by converting the xml into an xml string and using the below regex.

```
xmlString = xmlString.replace(/\d+>/g, '>');
```